# Query sum with greater than cell reference not working - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to combine query with numeric cell reference?
I have this formula :

`=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(C) where B > 1 label sum(C)''")`

But when I change to this, it doesn't work :

`=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(C) where B > '"&D1&"' label sum(C)''")`

I have 1 in cell D1. I don't have any idea how.
I need to make D1 as a dropdown choice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If D1 is numeric, remove `'`

```
=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(C) where B > "&D1&" label sum(C)''")
```